# Multiple records in same gridview line in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Is it possible to have two records per line in the same gridView in ASP.NET (I'm using C#)? Basically, let's assume this is what we have in our table:

```
Names
------
John
Paul
James
Edward
Sean
Kevin
```

Here's what I would like to see in the **gridView**:

```
John  | Paul
James | Edward
Sean  | Kevin
```

Is there a way to do this with a gridView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the templating offered by the ListView to get this type of custom layout:

[ListView Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My main reason for using a GridView is because I need paging. I'm wondering if that's available for a ListView.

Comment: Yes, ListView provides the best from both GridView and DataList templates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Great, I'll look into it more. Thanks.

Comment: After looking into it, ListView seems to be my solution. Thank you IrishChieftain.

Answer (score 2):

Not in a GridView but it is possible with a DataList, please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525467.aspx